# No se que pasa con json

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo eeste código de php:

```html
if($stmt->affected_rows==1){
               $respuesta=array(
               'respuesta'=>'correcto',
               'datos'=>array(
                    'id_insertado'=>$stmt->insert_id,
                    'nombre'=>$nombre,
                    'empresa'=>$empresa,
                    'telefono'=>$telefono
               )
               );
          }
          
          
 
  echo json_encode($respuesta,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

En javascript tengo lo siguiente:

```js
const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

               /* Apertura de la conexion */
               xhr.open('POST','inc/modelos/modelo-contactos.php',true);

               /* Paso de datos */
               xhr.onload=function(){
                    if(this.status===200){

                         /* El objeto xhr devuelve un string----------------------*/
                         console.log(xhr.responseText);
                         respuesta=xhr.responseText;


                         /* como el resultado que obtenemos es un string completo
                         podemos transformarlo en objeto a través de 
                         Json.parse para que javascript lo pueda leer. --------------- */
                         
                         /* Creacion del tr de la tabla. */
                         const nuevoContacto=document.createElement('tr');
                          nuevoContacto.innerHTML=`
                              <td> ${respuesta.datos.nombre} </td>
                              <td> ${respuesta.datos.empresa} </td>
                              <td> ${respuesta.datos.telefono} </td>
                         `;
```

Si lo hago de esa forma me dice que no se puede leer la propiedad nombre.
si lo hago con JSON.parse me dice que hay un error de un {
Pero la línea 
console.log(xhr.responseText); esta bien porque me devuelve esto:

```
1{
  "respuesta": "correcto",
  "datos": {
    "id_insertado": 69,
    "nombre": "Jes\u00fas",
    "empresa": "UNE",
    "telefono": "3105679432"
  }
}
```

La cuestion es que estoy tratando de insertar en una tabla de una web los datos que se introducen en un formulario. La pregunta es que al parecer JSON.parse no me funciona. Agradecería su apoyo.

Comment: he probado con JSON.parse sobre tu respuesta y me funciona sin problema var objeto = JSON.parse('{"respuesta":"correcto","datos":{ "id_insertado":69, "nombre":"Jes\u00fas", "empresa":"UNE","telefono":"3105679432"}}'); 
document.write(objeto.datos.nombre);

Answer (score 1):

El error esta en la cadena que estas regresando desde PHP.

```
1{  
   "respuesta":"correcto",
   "datos":{  
      "id_insertado":69,
      "nombre":"Jes\u00fas",
      "empresa":"UNE",
      "telefono":"3105679432"
   }
}
```

El `1` que tienes al principio de la cadena esta impidiendo que JSON.parse() de JavaScript evalúe correctamente la cadena obtenida. Verifica que no estés haciendo un `echo 1;` en alguna parte de tu script PHP. O de lo contrario, brinda un mejor contexto del script PHP a donde mandas la petición AJAX para ayudarte mejor.